# How to multiply column values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to double the value of column C in a table. Is there a built-in function to achieve this?

Current table

```
       A  B  C
    X  1  2  3
    Y  4  5  6
    Z  7  8  9
```

After running the T-SQL or any query table values should be as below

```
   A  B  C
X  1  2  6
Y  4  5  12
Z  7  8  18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To **select** the data:

   ```
   SELECT A,B,C*2 as C
   FROM TableName
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   A   B   C
   1   2   6
   4   5   12
   7   8   18
   ```

   See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be42e/1).
2. If you want to **update** the table:

   ```
   UPDATE TableName
   SET C=(C * 2)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just multiplying C by 2 (I mean `c*2`) makes any problem here

```
select A,  B,  C * 2 as c
from your_table
```

(OR)

If you want, create your own scalar UDF which will return the double value as

```
create function doubleval(@val int)
returns int
as
begin
return @val * 2;
end
```

Then, in your select use it as

```
select A,  B,  doubleval(C) as c
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, B, C *2 AS C
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

With Integer Data types its simple like you would do with in any other programming language just multiply divide or add the constant to the column name.